# grid items in container not in rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I used `Container` this caused all my grid items to be in columns not rows how can I fix it ?

[image]

[link for project](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dijkstra-lqjfyq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: did you check our answers? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this setup and it should work (remove `direction="row"` and add `container`)

```
  <Grid
    container
    sx={{
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      width: "100%",
      marginLeft: 0
    }}
    justify="center"
    spacing={4}
  >
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
      d
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
      e
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
      f
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
      g
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-noether-vxfecp?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: this works but when I open it in codesandbox browser or mobile the grid items start sticking to the left

Comment: it's because of `xs={12}` i guess. if you try with `xs={4}` it should display correctly even at mobile. if you open it in desktop browser and change the panel to be bigger so as for `sm` to take effect, you will see it working.

Comment: no that increases the number of grid items in a single row , `12` specifies that it will cover the whole grid space , making it `4` just adds more grids items in a row

Comment: aaaa yes sorry now i understand what you meant. it's the ` spacing={4}` that does that. if you remove it or make it e.g. 2, you will see them centered.

Comment: @Apostolos, If you copy's someone's answer give them creadit.

Comment: @venis sorry didnt understand what you mean.

Comment: yea, I tried that but I want spacing @Apostolos

Comment: @AdvityaSharma sorry i got it. please check my updated answer. `mui` automatically calculates some stuff and adds margins which overflow the container's area, so if you add `width: "100%",marginLeft: 0` it will center correctly the grid.

Comment: @AdvityaSharma did you check my updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give property `container` to your parent grid. Your return looks like,

```
return (
    <Container>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: "blue"
        }}
        justify="center"
        spacing={4}
      >
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
          d
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
          e
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
          f
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} sx={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
          g
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
```

Comment: the grid items start sticking to the left on a small screen

Comment: where do you want to stick your item? left, right or center?

Comment: center of the screen

Comment: remove ```spacing={4}``` from the parent grid.

Comment: yea but I want spacing

Comment: okay, currently I am busy in some another stuff, once I am available may be I will check it.